# Decrypt BitLocker-encrypted drive with BitLocker PIN under Windows PE

Tags: windows, bitlocker

After booting into Windows PE, the drive letters of my local drive are visible, but I'm unable to browse the files inside as my drive is encrypted with BitLocker. I can remember BitLocker startup PIN but misplaced the recovery key/password. Is there any way to decrypt my drive with BitLocker PIN? The command line "manage-bde" only accepts BitLocker recovery key/password, so it's useless. Please help! Thanks in advance.

Comment: What you want is impossible with the information you remember

Comment: Thanks @Ramhound. I have to reinstall and all my data is lost.